# How would I export data from Python to spreadsheet (Apple Numbers Format)?

Tags: numbers, python, automation

I'm currently trying to automate the export of data from a Python script to Apple's .numbers spreadsheet. Currently, I export from Pandas using .csv.

My specific use-case is to update an existing column from pandas and update an existing Apple spreadsheet. [image: Screenshot Of Numbers Spreadsheet]

The spreadsheet can be seen in the screenshot. I want to update the column named `Count` and make sure it is correctly tied with the column named `Item ID` so that the script will update the row in the column `Count` such that it corresponds to the correct id in the cell from `Item ID`. I also plan on having the script add new entries to the table when a new item id is discovered in one of my storage containers and then to copy and paste the formula as if I dragged the formula down from the cell above it.

I'm not asking for a full script to do all the things I ask as well that's not what this site is for, I'm just asking if there's a means of updating/saving a spreadsheet in the Apple Numbers format from Python. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) or simply [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)? Either way, you'll have to sacrifice formatting as pandas will not preserve the colors under `Sorted`.

Comment: Is the formatting important?  If it isn't, you should stay with CSV.  If it is, just write to an Excel file, which Numbers can read.

Comment: So, I currently use to_csv to generate the original csv I changed this from. I looked at to_excel and didn't see anything about Numbers format, so I didn't try that. The formatting is a bit important as it helps me determine what items need to be added to the sorter, so I can try excel and open in numbers.

I'd prefer to be able to merge this and the generated csv even if I can't use Pandas for it as I have formulas in this document to help with item calculation. I'll have to see if Pandas can preserve formulas.

Comment: So, when Googling earlier, I did not find this package, but did find it now. If it turns out to be the solution to my problem, I can write this as the answer and provide some examples on how to use it (based on my use-case in the question). https://pypi.org/project/numbers-parser/

Answer (score 1):

As it often happens, there is a special package to do so. To install, run

```
pip install numbers-parser
```

Suppose you have data you want to export, you either read it from the .numbers file, or modified somehow. For example, perform

```
doc = Document("old-sheet.numbers")
sheets = doc.sheets
tables = sheets[0].tables
table = tables[0]
table.write(1, 1, "This is new text")
table.write("B7", datetime(2020, 12, 25))
doc.save("new-sheet.numbers")
```

Data can be taken from pandas (read the doc searching by **pandas** keyword).

Full link to the packages PyPi docs: https://pypi.org/project/numbers-parser/